# How to edit/use environment specific configuration in apiconnect

Tags: apiconnect

IBM acquired Strongloop/Loopback and then turn it into 'apiconnect'
In loopback it's said you can add environment-specific configurations according to https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Environment-specific-configuration.html

It seem API Connect doesn't support it, does it? Is there an equivalent thing on API Connect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can define "**Parameters**" per API, and define values for paremeters in association with each **Catalog**. Then you can reference these parameters **$(paramName)** and get the value depending on the catalog in wihch you deploy. The parameter can be, a protol, a hostName, or any value you can configure in any policy in the API.

One example is to define the parameter `hostService`, this parameter can have the host of the endpoint to consume, then you define the value for each catalog, and use the parameter in the configuration.

```
$(hostservice)/contextroot/serviceConsume
```